# DNN 7 returning internal server error 500 on invalid tabname parameter

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm trying to set up a 404 error handling for my dnn instalation.

Enviroment:
DNN 07.01.02
IIS 8.5

I have created a DNN page on root named "404". When I try a nonexisting url like /asdf the 404 page is displayed correctly.

However, if I try /Default.aspx?tabname=asdf a 505 - internal server error page is shown.

Shouldn't those two behave be the same due to url rewriting.

Comment: AFAIK '?tabname=WhatEver' isn't a valid URL param. You probably want to try with a URL such '?tabid=WrongTabNumber'?

Comment: Have tried this url http: .../Default.aspx?tabname=Admin and it redirects me to admin page (even displays login form if I'm not logged in yet)